# Duplicates when creating view with entity reference

Tags: views, entities

I have a content type called Conference and there are various sections of data attached to each conference such as guest speakers, agenda, and local amenities. These sections of data are entity bundles. These attach to the content type with an entity reference field on the bundle, so each bundle has a list of conferences in a select list and you attach the bundle to conference by selecting it in this list.

The problem has come when creating a view to display the conference content type with it's corresponding entity bundle information, I am getting a views-row for every bundle, so the basic information from the content type is being duplicated 8-9 times and the bundle data is showing once, and each bundle shows on a views-row where all other bundle info is missing apart from its own.

I have tried to turn on DISTINCT in query settings but not working and if I turn on aggregation I get this error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
```

My View uses a contextual filter for nid and an entity reference relationship to pull the values through.

Any help is welcome, thanks as I am completely stuck with this. Maybe there is a work around, or maybe I need to set up my views differently?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [Views Distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) module.

Also, if there the results the logically different you can think of showing them in way that they look more of information rather than repeated results
For example if you group by conference, you can show aggregated speakers for a given conferenece

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't seem to work